# Evaluating $ \iint_{I^2}\sqrt{[1+(\theta-1)(x+y)]^2 - 4xy\theta(\theta-1)}dxdy$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Assume $\theta > 0$. I'm trying to evaluate

$$ \iint_{I^2}\sqrt{[1+(\theta-1)(x+y)]^2 - 4xy\theta(\theta-1)}dxdy$$

My integration skills got rusty and Wolfram for some reason does not suggest any tips. It should evaluate at $$ \frac{\theta^2+\theta \ln(\theta)−1}{3(\theta - 1)} $$ but am still not sure how to start separating the inner parts of the root.

Would appreciate any hints or suggestions!

Comment: Do we have any information about $I^2$? Is $\theta$ a constant?

Comment: I assume $I = [a,b]$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, yes?

Comment: @AlkaKadri yes, $I^2 = [0,1]^2$ and $\theta$ is fixed.

Comment: I suppose by "Wolfram" you mean "Wolfram Alpha" rather than "Wolfram Mathematica".  Using *Mathematica* and assuming that $\theta>0$, the result is $\frac{\theta ^2+\theta  \log (\theta )-1}{3 (\theta -1)}$.

Comment: @JimB yes, the free version, I suppose. I'll see if I can get my hands on Mathematica, it seems it would be of great help. I'll edit the question

Comment: How did you get an answer with Wolfram Alpha? I get 'standard computational time exceeded'. Any chance the 1 is not inside the square?

Comment: @ε-δ it is inside the square. I played around with $\theta$ equal to some primes, for numeric values it managed to succeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to prove your conjectured formula. I will write $t$ for $\theta$ and I will assume that $t>1$. The proof requires tons of algebra. Let's begin by writing the quantity inside the square as $[1+(t-1)y]+(t-1)x$. After expanding the square we get that the radicand is equal to
\begin{align*}
& [1+(t-1)y]^2+2[1+(t-1)y](t-1)x+(t-1)^2x^2-4t(t-1)xy\\
 &=[1+(t-1)y]^2+2[1-(t+1)y](t-1)x+(t-1)^2x^2.
\end{align*}

We next add and subtract $[1-(t+1)y]^2$ in order to complete the square; the last line now can be written as
$$4ty(1-y)+[1-(t+1)y+(t-1)x]^2.$$
For convenience I set $A(y)=4ty(1-y)$. Notice that for $0<y<1$, $A(y)>0$. Now we can rewrite the radicand as 
$$A(y)\Big[1+\Big(\frac{1-(t+1)y+(t-1)x}{\sqrt {A(y)}}\Big)^2 \,\Big].$$
Therefore since $\int\sqrt{1+x^2}\,dx=\frac12(x\sqrt{1+x^2}+\ln|x+\sqrt{1+x^2}|),$
we can make a substitution to get that

\begin{align*}
& \int_0^1\sqrt {[1+(t-1)(x+y)]^2-4t(t-1)xy} \,dx= \int_0^1\sqrt{A(y)\Big[1+\Big(\frac{1-(t+1)y+(t-1)x}{\sqrt {A(y)}}\Big)^2 \,\Big]}dx\\
&=\frac{A(y)}{(t-1)}\int_{a(y)}^{b(y)}\sqrt{1+u^2}\,du =\frac{A(y)}{2(t-1)}\Big[u\sqrt{1+u^2}+\ln|u+\sqrt{1+u^2}|\Big]_{a(y)}^{b(y)},
\end{align*}
where $a(y)=\frac{1-(t+1)y}{\sqrt{A(y)}}$ and $b(y)=\frac{t-(t+1)y}{\sqrt{A(y)}}$. It now remains to compute the integral of the above expression with respect to $y$ on [0,1].

After some algebra (that I am skipping here) we see that $A(y)+(b(y))^2=[t-(t-1)y]^2$ and $A(y)+(a(y))^2=[1+(t-1)y]^2$. It follows that (using the assumption $t>1$)

\begin{align*}
A(y)b(y)\sqrt{1+(b(y))^2}&=A(y)\frac{t-(t+1)y}{\sqrt{A(y)}}\frac{\sqrt{A(y)+(b(y))^2}}{\sqrt{A(y)}}\\
&=[t-(t+1)y][t-(t-1)y]=t^2-2t^2y+(t^2-1)y^2.
\end{align*}
A similar computation yields
$$A(y)a(y)\sqrt{1+(a(y))^2}=1-2y-(t^2-1)y^2.$$
We can now easily compute that
\begin{align*}
 &\frac{1}{2(t-1)}\int_0^1 A(y)\big[b(y)\sqrt{1+(b(y))^2}-a(y)\sqrt{1+(a(y))^2}\,\big]\,dy\\
 &=\frac{1}{2(t-1)}\int_0^1t^2-2t^2y+(t^2-1)y^2-1+2y+(t^2-1)y^2\,dy\\
 &=\frac{1}{2(t-1)}\int_0^1(t^2-1)(1-2y+2y^2)\,dy=\frac{1}{3}(t+1).
\end{align*}

Now we move to the logarithmic part. We have

\begin{align*}
\ln\big|b(y)+\sqrt{1+(b(y))^2}\big|=\ln\big|\frac{t-(t+1)y}{\sqrt{A(y)}}+\sqrt{\frac{A(y)+(b(y))^2}{A(y)}}\big|\\
=\ln\frac{t-(t+1)y+t-(t-1)y}{\sqrt{A(y)}}=\ln(2t(1-y))-\frac{1}{2}\ln A(y).
\end{align*}

At this point integrating the quantity 
$$A(y)\ln\big|b(y)+\sqrt{1+(b(y))^2}\big|=A(y)[\ln(2t(1-y))-\frac{1}{2}\ln A(y)]$$
shouldn't be too hard, since $A(y)$ is a polynomial, but we can simplify it further before integrating. Using properties of logarithms we get

\begin{align*}
A(y)[\ln(2t(1-y))-\frac{1}{2}\ln A(y)]&=\ln(2t)A(y)+A(y)\ln(1-y)-\frac{1}{2}A(y)[\ln(4t)+\ln y+\ln(1-y)]\\
&=\frac{\ln t}{2} A(y)+\frac{1}{2}A(y)\ln(\frac{1-y}{y}).
\end{align*}
After a similar computation we find

\begin{align*}
\ln\big|a(y)+\sqrt{1+(a(y))^2}\big|=\ln\big|\frac{1-(t+1)y}{\sqrt{A(y)}}+\sqrt{\frac{A(y)+(a(y))^2}{A(y)}}\big|\\
=\ln\big|\frac{1-(t+1)y+1+(t-1)y}{\sqrt{A(y)}}\big|=\ln(2(1-y))-\frac{1}{2}\ln A(y)
\end{align*}
and

\begin{align*}
A(y)[\ln(2(1-y))-\frac{1}{2}\ln A(y)]&=\ln(2)A(y)+A(y)\ln(1-y)-\frac{1}{2}A(y)[\ln(4t)+\ln y+\ln(1-y)]\\
&=-\frac{\ln t}{2} A(y)+\frac{1}{2}A(y)\ln(\frac{1-y}{y}).
\end{align*}
Therefore

\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{2(t-1)}\int_0^1 A(y)\big[\ln\big|b(y)+\sqrt{1+(b(y))^2}\big|-\ln\big|a(y)+\sqrt{1+(a(y))^2}\big|\big]\,dy\\
&=\frac{1}{2(t-1)}\int_0^1\frac{\ln t}{2} A(y)+\frac{1}{2}A(y)\ln(\frac{1-y}{y})+\frac{\ln t}{2} A(y)-\frac{1}{2}A(y)\ln(\frac{1-y}{y})\,dy\\
&=\frac{1}{2(t-1)}\int_0^1 \ln t\, 4t\, y(1-y)\,dy=\frac{t\ln t}{3(t-1)}.
\end{align*}

We conclude that the value of the given integral is $\dfrac{1}{3}\big(t+1+\dfrac{t\ln t}{t-1}\big)$, as conjectured.

Comment: Excellent job, thank you! Will take notes on some of the tricks you pulled there :)

Comment: Thanks. The main idea was to complete the square to get an integral of the form $\int\sqrt{A(1+u^2)}du$. That's why I asked you if the 1 could be outside the squared expression; that would have made the first step easier. However it still seems like a miracle that everything worked out so nicely. Where did you find this?